# Naming Convention for Login, User and Roles?

Tags: sql-server, users, logins, role, naming-convention

What are the Naming Conventions for a Login, A database User and a Database role?

Is there any best practice to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there won't be one documented for objects like logins users and roles. Just to make a note to keep the names not very familiar or similar to database name or any common naming convention that can be prone to hack. Check your company standards how existing environments uses the setup, as I am sure this won't be the first of them.